# Fork and exec mechanism

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm reading about the `fork & exec` mechanism in Linux. Here are my questions in the topic.

1. Does it mean that typing a simple command like `ls` at command prompt makes the bash process to `fork` (duplicates itself) and then issue an `exec` call to substitute the cloned bash code with ls command code?
2. Regarding the exaple above and according to the doc: 
   `child process has the same environment as its parent`
   does it mean that `ls` command process would have an access to all the enviroment variables defined so far in the bash?
3. Does the mechanism applies only to binaries like build-in commands or to shell scripts too?

Answer (score 1):

1. Nope, it spawns `/usr/bin/ls` as a child process. You may want to play with `strace` if you're interested in these kind of things:

   ```
   [foo@turtle ~]$ strace -f -eexecve -o bash.strace bash
   [foo@turtle ~]$ ls
   bash.strace
   [foo@turtle ~]$ exit
   [foo@turtle ~]$ cat bash.strace 
   26213 execve("/usr/bin/bash", ["bash"], [/* 37 vars */]) = 0
   26214 +++ exited with 0 +++
   26213 --- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=26214, si_uid=10003, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
   26230 execve("/usr/bin/ls", ["ls", "--color=auto"], [/* 37 vars */]) = 0
   26230 +++ exited with 0 +++
   26213 --- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=26230, si_uid=10003, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
   26213 +++ exited with 0 +++
   ```
2. Yes, it does kind of, sort of: there is a difference whether it is exported or not:

   ```
   [foo@turtle ~]$ DIR_I_WANT_TO_LS=/home/foo 
   [foo@turtle ~]$ ls $DIR_I_WANT_TO_LS
   bar  bash.strace  ls_from_a_script.sh
   [foo@turtle ~]$ set -x
   [foo@turtle ~]$ ls $DIR_I_WANT_TO_LS
   bar  bash.strace  ls_from_a_script.sh
   [foo@turtle ~]$ ./ls_from_a_script.sh 
   $DIR_I_WANT_TO_LS=
   bar  bash.strace  ls_from_a_script.sh
   $DIR_I_WANT_TO_LS=/home/foo/bar
   [foo@turtle ~]$ export DIR_I_WANT_TO_LS
   [foo@turtle ~]$ ./ls_from_a_script.sh 
   $DIR_I_WANT_TO_LS=/home/foo
   bar  bash.strace  ls_from_a_script.sh
   $DIR_I_WANT_TO_LS=/home/foo/bar
   ```
3. No, it works perfectly with any program (binary, shell, ruby, python, lua, node...). The latter usually have a struct often called `ENV` for this.

Answer (score 0):

> Does it mean that typing a simple command like ls at command prompt makes the bash process to fork (duplicates itself) and then issue an exec call to substitute the cloned bash code with ls command code?

Basically yes. Though the technical details may vary:

- On modern OSes, fork() is fast due to copy-on-write. But on some older systems, every fork had to make a full copy of the process' memory, so shells instead used [vfork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/vfork.2.html) which only created a new process but shared the same memory.
- (On Linux, the fork(3) function in libc actually uses the [clone(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clone.2.html) syscall. The end result is still the same though.)
- The libc has various [exec…(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html) functions, which all translate to the [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) syscall.

> Regarding the exaple above and according to the doc:  child process has the same environment as its parent does it mean that ls command process would have an access to all the enviroment variables defined so far in the bash?

It would have access to *a copy* of those environment variables. (So if `ls` did any changes, they would not go upwards.)

Note that not all bash variables are automatically *environment* variables – only those explicitly 'exported' to the environment. (You can use `declare -p` to see all variables, exported or not.)

> Does the mechanism applies only to binaries like build-in commands or to shell scripts too?

It also applies to shell scripts – the kernel considers [scripts with `#!`](http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/shebang/) to be executable, and passes them to whatever "interpreter" was specified in the `#!` line.

(Linux also has "binfmt_misc" which allows defining and exec'ing custom formats – for example, it can be made to run .exe's via Wine.)

Although if the kernel rejects the exec call, some shells will *still* try to run the script manually by exec'ing /bin/sh with that script. (In fact, sometimes that's even done by the libc – there's a mention in glibc's `exec(3)` manpage.)